# Django Render List of Dictionaries to a template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a list of dictionaries with same key information. How can I pass this list of dictionaries to a Django template ?

```
listdict = [{'product':'specs','price':'12'}, {'product':'shoes','price':'30'}]
```

When trying to send this list via views file to template it fails with an error indicating that only dictionaries are allowed.

Here is the code from views file

```
return render(request, 'recordings/extensionrecording.html',listDict)
```

Here is the html block-

```
      <tbody>
                                {%for list in listDict%}
                                {%for elements in list%}
                               
                                
                                
                            <tr>
                             
<td class="body-item fonts-style display-4">{{elements.product}}</td>
<td class="body-item fonts-style display-4">{{elements.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass these as an entry of the dictionary:

```
return render(request, 'recordings/extensionrecording.html',{'listDict': listDict})
```

Then in the template, you can render these with:

```
{%for item in listDict %}
    {{ item.product }}
    {{ item.price }}
{% endfor %}
```